# How to run IR (LLVM) code for profiling purpose?

Tags: clang, llvm

I have a C function that I've compiled to LLVM IR assembly. I would like to run "virtually" this IR code, just to count the number of instructions executed each second, by opcode (number of add, number of ret etc). What solutions are availables ? I would like to know if this is possible with the clang/llvm tools and API.

An application of this would be to estimate the number of operations executed by an algorithm, for which a mathematical analysis is hard.

Comment: That isn't going to be a meaningful application profiling since there's no match with platform-specific opcodes. Just wanted to clarify it in case that was the intended behavior.

Comment: I actually want to count the number of LLVM opcodes. It's like if I had a processor that can run IR code and I want to count the number of instructions it runs per second.

Comment: Tool recommendations are off-topic.  Please edit your question to make it on-topic.  For example asking about _specific_ things.